# How to turn $(document).click() event on/off or other solution

Tags: javascript, jquery, mouseevent

I have a DIV tag which when clicked I want to start a process, after which clicking anywhere on the document I want to end the process. So far I have tried this:

```
$(document).click(end_process);
$('div_tag_id').click(start_process);
```

This is no good as clicking to start the process also ends the process immediately afterwards. Any ideas?

Comment: Well that was much easier than I expected, good old jQuery! Thanks all who replied.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you want something like this:

```
$('div_tag_id').click(function(e) {
   e.stopPropagation();
   start_process(e);
});
```

See:

http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/

Comment: Good idea to pass on the event object in order to emulate the original code, though you may also want to set the `this` value. `start_process.call( this, e );`.

Comment: True, that's probably what I would do, I was just attempting to duplicate the arguments that would have been previously sent to the method.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`stopPropagation`](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/) in your handler:

```
$('div_tag_id').click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    start_process();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Sure, you just want to stop the event from bubbling up in your start_process handler:

```
start_process(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
}
```

Edit: Looks like everyone said about the same thing at the same time. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

You can call `.stopPropagation()` in the `start_process` function to stop the event from bubbling up to the `document`:

```
function start_process(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    //..your code here
}
```

Here is the documentation for `.stopPropagation()`: http://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/

Answer (score 0):

Use `stopPropagation` to stop the click from propagating to the parent.

```
$('div_tag_id').click(function(e){
    start_process();
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

alternatively, just add `stopPropagation` into the body of `start_process`.